# Why in spring-core 4.1.5 source The class DefaultNamingPolicy is non-existent

Tags: java, spring

I'm download the source from [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-core/),but the source can't compile success,because lot of Class is non-existent like `org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultNamingPolicy`

[image]

How can I do to compile it successful?

Comment: Can you tell us what commands you're trying to run to build Spring?

Comment: copying the source(spring-core) and pom.xml，then import to IDEA

Comment: Spring uses gradle, not Maven. Its README explains how to import the project in your IDE. Spring repackages CGLIB (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/build.gradle#L345), and the DefaultNamingPolicy is thus automatically generated by the build.

Comment: Thinks，I have already find the gradle task cglibRepackJar